# Is there a solution like leaflet-knn in ArcGIS (js-api) for finding the nearest point in a geoJSON multi-point feature to a given point?

Tags: leaflet, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

This is how i get the closest point on a geoJSON line to a given point using [leaflet-knn](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-knn):

> Given a point, find the nearest points to it. If the index contains multi-point features, like lines, polygons, and so on, it returns points in those features and can return more than one point in each feature.

```
const line= L.geoJSON(this.lineFromGeoJson, {
      onEachFeature: (feature, layer) => {
        layer.bindPopup(
          'insignificant feature stuff here',
          {maxHeight: this.screenHeight, maxWidth: this.screenWidth, autoPan: true});
      }
    }).addTo(this.map);

const nearest = leafletKnn(line).nearest(L.latLng(this.lat, this.longt), 1);
```

Is there anything similar in [@arcgis/core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@arcgis/core)?

I'm already using the [geodesicUtils.geodesicLengths](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-support-geodesicUtils.html#geodesicLengths) from arcgis to get the length of this geoJSON line and i figured perhaps there was a solution for this in arcgis that i have not found?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use `geometryEngine.nearestVertices` method ([ArcGIS JS API - esriGeometry](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-geometryEngine.html#nearestVertices)).

Now, this method actually takes a geometry as parameter instead of a layer, so you will probably will need to "create" the geometry using the layer or better a subset of the layer.

You can get a subset of the layer (set of features) with a distance query on the layer using [ArcGIS JS API - Query](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-rest-support-Query.html).